# Mocha test hangs with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using `mocha` and `chai` to test `getUserProfile`:

```
describe("Testing the getUserInfo methods for the model", function() {

    describe("testing getProfileFromModel function", function(done) {
        var user;
        var getProfileFromModel;
        var savePromise;

        beforeEach(function(done) {
            mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/login_test");
            mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() {
                console.log("connected to mongoose");
            });
            mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", function(){
                console.log("disconnected from mongoose");
            });

            mongoose.connection.on("error", function(){
                console.log("error connecting to mongoose");
            });

            mongoose.connection.once("open",function() {
            user = new User({
                local:{
                    email:"test@test.com",
                    password:"keyboardcat"
                }
            });
            mongoose.connection.once("open",function() {
                user = new User({
                   local:{
                        email:"test@test.com",
                        password:"keyboardcat"
                   }
                });
                savePromise = user.saveAsync()
                    .then(function(data){
                       console.log("saved",data);
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        throw err;
                    })
                    .finally(function(){
                        done();
                    });
            });
        });
            getProfileFromModel = getUserProfile.getProfileFromModel;   
        });

        afterEach(function(done){
            user.removeAsync({_id:user._id})
                .then(function(data){
                    console.log("model has been deleted",data);     
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    throw err;
                })
                .finally(function(){
                    mongoose.connection.close();
                    done(); 
                })
        });

        it("is expected to return a user with a string parameters", function(done) {
            var id = user._id;
            var projection = "local.email";
            savePromise.then(function(data){
                var getProfile = getProfileFromModel(User);
                getProfile(id,projection)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        expect(data).to.equal({
                            email:"test@test.com"
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        throw err;
                    })
                    .finally(function(){
                        done();
                    })
            });
        });
    });

});
});
```

While debugging using `node-inspectort` I found that the beforeEach gets executed,following which it disconnects from `mongoose`.

Comment: Shouldn't you try saving after `mongoose` connects?

Comment: @mostruash fixed that,code now `connection.once('open',fn)`

Comment: Shouldn't you first connect to the DB before describing your tests? Unless you're testing whether your code connects to the server (which is a strange thing to test for unless you're writing a DB), your `beforeEach()` code usually goes outside your model tests. That way you only test for the actual model operations and not anything else (i.e: the definition of unit tests).

Comment: @Bwaxxlo I am not sure I understand where the mongoose connection code should go,because there are other tests in the module that do not depend on `mongoose`.Could you illustrate to clarify?

Comment: @vamsiampolu The mongoose connection should go before the model tests. So, unless you have your tests all in a single file, you should structure your tests according to their functionalities. All model tests have to be done after the connection is established. After the tests, you can close the connections